# how do I fix the overlay "overflow: hidden;" instead of the entire body

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this hamburger menu on the right side of the navbar which when clicked should pop open overlay and be full screen black and un-scrollable(just the overlay) but right now when it's clicked is scrollable and not full screen black, I don't know what went wrong, any help would be really appreciated, thanx!

```js
$(function() {

  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("open");

  });

});
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#brandname {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Circular Std Black;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-line {
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-line-2 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-line-3 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
  transform: translateY(7px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-7px) translateY(50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-circle {
  background-color: #E095F0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.menu.open .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(60);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-overlay {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1001;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.menu-overlay.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div id="brandname">Test</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="menu-circle"></span>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-overlay">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>


</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See adjustments to the CSS inline below, but here are the major points:

The overlay should not be using Flexbox. If you want the layout within the overlay to use Flexbox, then set that up on the elements it contains.

The element itself should not be in the HTML as a child of the main content if you are going to size it using percents, because then it will only be as big as the parent. Instead, use `vh` and `vw` (Viewport Height and Viewport Width) units.

Set the `top` and `left` CSS properties to position the overlay at the top-left of the screen.

Don't use `visibility` to hide the overlay, use `display:none` and then `display:block` to bring it back.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("open");

  });

});
```

```css
/* ------------- */
.menu-overlay {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
  display:hidden;
}
.menu-overlay.open {
  position: fixed; 
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;  
  
  opacity:1;
  display:block;
  z-index: 1001;  
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#brandname {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Circular Std Black;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-line {
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-line-2 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-line-3 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
  transform: translateY(7px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-7px) translateY(50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-circle {
  background-color: #E095F0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.menu.open .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(60);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-overlay">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
<nav class="nav">
    <div id="brandname">Test</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="menu-circle"></span>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cheers, but how do I make the overlay "overflow: hidden;" when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Scott Marcus for fixing the layout but the overflow was still not working so I added a toggle-class in js, It works just fine but lemme know otherwise if it contains any DOM errors. Cheers!

```
$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});

.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```